# How to find the x path of an element when the python selenium script clicks a button which in turn opens in a new window (element is in new window)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, scripting

The python(selenium) script fails when a new chrome window opens upon clicking a button. I have passed the x-path of the element from the new window(extracted the x-path manually) in my script. The script runs and fails with an error **selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="3131"]"}**

How can I resolve this issue ?

Expecting a method to pass the script to newly opened window and find the x-path of the element I intent to locate

Answer (score 2):

The selenium documentation shows how to switch to a new window quite well and once you switched to the new window you just work as if you were in the main window.

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    # Open URL
    driver.get("https://seleniumhq.github.io")

    # Setup wait for later
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Store the ID of the original window
    original_window = driver.current_window_handle

    # Check we don't have other windows open already
    assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1

    # Click the link which opens in a new window
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "new window").click()

    # Wait for the new window or tab
    wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

    # Loop through until we find a new window handle
    for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break

    # Wait for the new tab to finish loading content
    wait.until(EC.title_is("SeleniumHQ Browser Automation"))
```